# Security with EJB + JPA

Tags: security, jsf, jakarta-ee, ejb

Could anyone help me finding a good book or tutorial about implementing security using EJB and JSF with database authentication and authorization?

I am new to EJB and JPA I would really appreciate any help.

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good tutorial is this: http://netbeans.org/kb/trails/java-ee.html from Netbeans! It will tell you exactly what to use and why to use it! It is perfect for a new beginner, as I learned a lot from it! You could also find in there "Securing the Application" ( http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/ecommerce/security.html ) link to see an example regarding authentication and authorization!

Hope this helps! :)